# How to change Excel Cell color according to Value?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

So basically my idea is fairly easy. I have an excel file where i have a column(D)
and i wanna have every row checked for the lenght of the column(except the first one, that's a name). If the value is higher then 0, the cell should be green, if it's lower then 0 then it should be red and 0 is gray colored. I know this could be possible with a loop, but i don't know how and i can't find any good information about how to approach this...

So i got this already:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pythoncom

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    #Excel
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Downloads\\RELEARNING\\output.xlsx')
    ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells(1,4).Value = "Coin Toss Results"  #This is Row D
    ws.Columns.AutoFit()
    wb.Save()
    excel.Application.Quit()
```

What is the most efficient approach for this?

Thanks for answering in advance,

Jan

PS: OpenPyXL is tagged, because i think win32com uses the same commands as openpyxl, if i am not mistaken, else remove tag...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a cell's fill RGB color with pywin32 in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444207/setting-a-cells-fill-rgb-color-with-pywin32-in-excel)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the sample code which should work as long as you insert before `wb.Save()`, note that we used a function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338319/8350440):

```
for i in range(2,5):   # Assuming there is Cell(D2)=1, Cell(D3)=0, Cell(D4)=-1
    cell = ws.Cells(i,4)
    if cell.Value < 0:
        cell.Interior.Color = rgbToInt((255,0,0)) # red
    elif cell.Value == 0:
        cell.Interior.Color = rgbToInt((211,211,211)) # grey
    elif cell.Value > 0:
        cell.Interior.Color = rgbToInt((0,255,0)) # green
    else:
        print('Error.')
```