# Excel Border Color with Xlwings in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Using xlwings in Python, I've been able to add cell borders and set their weight. But unfortunately every time I try to change the border color, the code gets stuck

```
import xlwings as xw
sheet = xw.sheets[0]
cells = sheet.range((2,2),(2,6))
cells.api.Borders(11).Weight = 3
cells.api.Borders(11).Color = '#ffffff' # This line gets the code stuck
```

Any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338319/16120011
def rgbToInt(rgb):
    colorInt = rgb[0] + (rgb[1] * 256) + (rgb[2] * 256 * 256)
    return colorInt

wb = xw.Book()

sheet = wb.sheets[0]

cells = sheet.range((2, 2), (2, 6))
cells.api.Borders(11).Weight = 3
cells.api.Borders(11).Color = rgbToInt((0, 0, 0)) #black color
```

Output :

[image]